# Custom Spacing on PGF legend

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to change the spacing of a single legend entry in a PGF bar plot. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,5) (3,2)};
        \addlegendentry{(a)}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,6) (3,1)};
        \addlegendentry{(b)}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,4) (2,4) (3,4)};
        \addlegendentry{(c)}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which generates the following figure

[image: Minimal Working Example for this question]

What I want is to create a space between (a) and (b) in the legend, while not creating a space between (b) and (c) (that is, I don't want to change the `row sep`). The ideia is to separate (a) from (b) and (c) in order to highlight that (a) is the result of a work and (b) and (c) are the result of another work in a presentation.

I tried to create a custom legend using `\label` and `\ref`, but this changes the bars (in the legend) to lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the spacing of the legend entry by including `text depth=2ex, anchor=mid` in the `\addlegendentry` options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,5) (3,2)};
        \addlegendentry[text depth=2ex, anchor=mid]{(a)}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,6) (3,1)};
        \addlegendentry{(b)}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,4) (2,4) (3,4)};
        \addlegendentry{(c)}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but it seams that conflicts with `every axis legend/.append style={nodes={right}}` for some reason (which is not in my MWH, but it is in my real code). But I changed to `every axis legend/.append style={nodes={left}}` and obtained the desired result.

Comment: @RafaelSchouery: In that case, you can use `anchor=mid west` instead of `anchor=mid`.

Answer (score 3):

Not the best solution, but you could add an empty legend entry with

```
\addlegendimage{empty legend}
\addlegendentry{}
```

The spacing can be increased by adding a zero width rule in the legend entry, e.g.

```
\addlegendentry{\rule{0pt}{3pt}}
```

Change `3pt` to modify the spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ybar]
        \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,5) (3,2)};
        \addlegendentry{(a)}
        \addlegendimage{empty legend}
        \addlegendentry{}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,6) (3,1)};
        \addlegendentry{(b)}
        \addplot coordinates {(1,4) (2,4) (3,4)};
        \addlegendentry{(c)}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I can't adjust the spacing, right?

Comment: @RafaelSchouery You can, to a certain extent at least, by adding a zero width rule in the legend entry. I'll update my answer. Edit: Jake's answer is of course much better anyway.